# What is the running time of this modified selection sort algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, selection-sort

I'm prepping for software developer interviews and reviewing algorithms. I'm stuck on a question that asks "Given a modified selection sort algorithm that returns in sorted order the *k* smallest elements in an array of size *n* what is its worst case running time in terms of *n* and *k*?"

Modified selection sort algorithm:

```
A = [1...n]  //an array of size n

for i = 1 to k
  smallest = A[i]
  for j = i + 1 to n
    if A[j] < A[smallest]
      smallest = j
  swap (A[i], A[smallest])
```

I'm guessing it's O(nk) but not sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer loop runs k times. For each iteration of outer loop, the inner loop makes O(n) iterations.

More mathematically, the inner loop runs:

```
(n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + .... + (n-k) times
= n*k - k*(k+1)/2
= k* (n - k/2 -1/2)
~ k * n

Hence, Complexity = O(n*k)
```

Comment: What if there were a while statement within the inner for loop? How do you calculate that?

Comment: @MNRC If there was a while statement inside the inner loop, then the statements inside the while loop would be executed k*n * (no. of while iterations) times. Hence another factor would be added in the complexity. It would become O(n*k*w) where w is the number of iterations of the innermost while loop (eg. while (i < w) i++).

Comment: Thanks! You should teach this in college, much clearer explanation than my professor!

Comment: user1990169 : change your user name :)

Comment: @cegprakash Why do you think I should change my username? what's in a name?

Answer (score 2):

```
O(nk)
```

Outer loop picks `k` elements and inner loop picks `n` elements